# Creating a drawer inside of UITableViewCell like Twitter app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, twitter

There is this set of button/options when you're creating a new tweet that I am trying to replicate in my iPhone app. I have encountered a few obstacles. One, I don't know exactly what the developers at Twitter put inside of the UITableViewCell in order to get the buttons evenly spaced inside of the cell. Two, I'm interested in how they created that little up arrow inside the same cell that you choose your options from. Lastly, how did they create the swiping motion between views inside of the bottom cell when a user clicks between the first and second option. It looks like this:

[image]

I really like the way that this looks, and it would work perfectly for my app. I just don't even know where to start with building this beyond setting up the cell. Does anyone have a library or insight that they have and are willing to share?

Answer (score 0):

When we were looking to do something very similar, I found this extremely helpful site: [How does the Twitter iPhone app implement side swiping on a table?](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/04/14/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-side-swiping-on-a-table/)

Perhaps this can help you out in your endeavors.